# syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: c++, c, unix, named-pipes

I am doing some work in unix with c++. I am trying to create a named pipe between my two programs, and send some text back and forth between them. Everything compiles fine, but when I make my system call to run server.cpp I get this error message.

```
./server.cpp: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./server.cpp: line 8: 'void test()'
```

What is causing this error? I do not have much experience with unix or named pipes so I am kind of stumped.

Here is my code

client.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
   int fd;

   mkfifo("home/damil/myPipe", 0666);

   fd=open("home/damil/myPipe", O_WRONLY);
   write(fd,"test", sizeof("test")+1);

   system("./server.cpp");
   close(fd);

   return 1; 
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void test()
{
   int fd;
   char * comm;

   fd = open("home/damil/myPipe", O_RDONLY);   
   read(fd, comm, 1024);
   printf(comm);
   close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be running binary and not .cpp file?

Comment: server.cpp also needs a `main()` function (among other things)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a C++ error, but rather a UNIX error. By running `system("./server.cpp")` you're trying to run the `.cpp` file as if it were a compiled executable. The system thinks it's a shell script and hits a syntax error as soon as it gets past the `#include`s (which, in shell, are parsed as comments and are thus ignored).

You need to compile `server.cpp` and run the resulting binary. (Note: you'll probably want to rename `test()` to `main()`.)

```
g++ -Wall -o server server.cpp
```

Then in `client.cpp`, change the system call to:

```
system("./server");
```